# iis startup delay with aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis

Environment: Windows Server 2003; IIS 6, ASP.NET 2.0.50727

I'm going crazy with a brand new web server that we set up (note that this problem doesn't happen on our other web servers which have the same configuration). When loading and asp.net app the first time, the page hangs for over a full minute before showing the page in the browser. After it loads the first page, everything runs very quickly.

Note 1: You will probably say that the application is being compiled for the first time. But I've ruled that out. I put trace messages EVERYWHERE in the app and all the trace messages run within a second of requesting the page. Thus, the app compiles and runs immediately. But when the app is finished rendering the page and my last trace message is printed, nothing happens. IIS is doing something behind the scenes for a full minute before transferring the finished page along http to the user's browser.

Note 2: We found that after hitting the app the first time and things run fine, if we wait an hour then we get the delay again. Thus, IIS has something in its cache that it clears out after an hour and causes our site to stall again.

Note 3: Between each test we stop/start IIS to force it to hang upon loading the app.

Note 4: We watched the Task Manager to see if IIS was spiking and taking up a lot of resources processing something. But that wasn't it. We did see a very quick spike to 50% immediately before the browser showed the page, but for the previous 60 seconds there was only 1% usage on the server.

Note 5: On another test I created a HelloWorld.html page and this does not cause IIS to hang. Thus, it has something to do with calling the ASP.NET library the very first time it sends a rendered page across http. Also, since the app has already been compiled and runs instantly, it's just the part of asp.net that sends the rendered page to the user's browser that causes the delay.

Any ideas? We are a a loss here. All of our other web servers are setup the same way and work fine, but this is a new install. So there must be a configuration setting that was missed or maybe something needs to be installed?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Do you read on the event viewer any asp.net error ? You must have at least some time outs events - and close connections from clients that drop the threads.

Comment: We looked at the event viewer but didn't see anything. I'll do more testing and watch it again. Also, this server has no traffic except for our testing. So no clients dropping threads or anything like that. Just us doing simple page requests and watching is hang.

Comment: The other issue can be a fast pool reset, you may have similar configuration, but the pools can be different in the settings. Check them out if you made any restart of them on eg memory grow, or too fast etc.

Comment: Also use the process explorer from sys internals to see and check how the system is, what thread you run, if the iis is make restarts on asp.net etc...

Comment: I'll see if they let me install Process Explorer on our production server and check it out. It does sound something is timing out behind the scenes when passing the rendered page to http, but it doesn't make sense why it would only timeout the first time it's called. It seems like whatever process is in charge of passing the final HTML to the browser is initializing something and loading it into memory and once it's loaded all page requests go fast (until an hour of no activity where it has to re-load that process again). Grrr.

Comment: try to increase the compile time out on web.config as: `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="260"`

Comment: Per my 'answer' below, deleting the app and then re-adding it worked great... for a while... I could stop/start IIS multiple times and the app always ran instantly. I thought it was fixed for good. But now I just tried again (it has been sitting idle for the past couple of hours) and now it is back to hanging on the first request. Why would deleting/adding it from the app pool work initially, but now it has gone back to its old ways? Does the app pool have anything to do with passing a rendered page to the browser?  Ugh...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the servers, then make sure that app pool recycling is actually logged to the event logs

cscript adsutil.vbs get w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/LogEventOnRecycle

you can set it to log everything with
cscript adsutil.vbs Set w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/LogEventOnRecycle 255

[See more here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332088)

Then check if there were any recycles.

App initialization, creation the worker process, threads, load the app domain and all the references dll's can take some time, that's normal, but that 1 minute delay is something else probably.

Try to precompile the app on the server and see if that helps
aspnet_compiler -m /LM/W3SVC/[site id ]/Root/[your appname]

If you want to dig deeper, you can check the event trace  ETW.

1. logman query providers
2. Save the IIS /ASP.NET related Guids to a file like iisproviders.txt
3. logman start ExampleTrace -pf iisproviders.txt -ets -rt
4. reproduce
5. LogParser "SELECT * FROM ExampleTrace" -i:ETW
6. logman stop ExampleTrace -ets

You can find more here[Troubleshooting appdomain restarts and other issues with ETW tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-etw-tracing.aspx)

I would also check the w3wp.exe with procexp if it has a TCP connection time out or with Procmon for other clues.

If you have experience with windbg, then you can make a request to the app then quickly attach the debugger to the process

```
windbg -p [process id of the app pool]
.loadby sos mscorwks
g
```

and take it from there. If there are exceptions, process crash, etc you should be able to catch it...

Once we had a weird server issue like this and a .NET reinstall solved the problem, still not sure what was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Could be some aspnet.config settings on this box that are different from others.  Have you tried copying over their config files to this server?  There appears to be certificate options along with registry modifications that you can do to remove some lag time during the initial load of a page (precompiling aside)

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/04/26/asp-net-application-loads-slowly-the-first-time.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/10/28/web-site-stops-responding-for-15-25-seconds.aspx)

Comment: the aspnet.config files are identical (and pretty simplistic).  [code] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
        <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
        <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
        <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>[/code]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to check on is if there are any database access going on on your page load. That might be blocking the creation of the page during initial page load. Then when the query is cached (either by the db engine or another cache mechanism like memcached), subsequent page loads work as normal.

As per your last comment,

> I could stop/start IIS multiple times and the app always ran instantly. I thought it was fixed for good. But now I just tried again (it has been sitting idle for the past couple of hours) and now it is back to hanging on the first request.

This could mean that the cache has expired and thus needs to hit the database once again, causing the delay in page load.